# JSON literal in script with escaped quotes

Tags: javascript, json

Why will the following give a JSON parsing error in browsers.  It looks be valid JSON saved in a literal string and then passed into a parser.  Can we not put stringifed json into a javascript string and then parse?

```
<script>
  var text='{"value": "I said, \"hello\""}';
  var selectGroupsRows =JSON.parse(text);
</script>
```

Comment: ``\`` is the escape character in string literals *as well as* JSON strings. The value of `'{"value": "I said, \"hello\""}'` is `{"value": "I said, "hello""}`. As you can see, it doesn't contain any backslashs, but the inner `"` need to be escaped.

Comment: *"Can we not put stringifed json into a javascript string and then parse?"* Depends what you mean with that exactly. In general one has to be careful to put arbitrary content into a string **literal**, because string literals have their own parsing rules (such as treatment of ``\`` and the fact that `'` and `"` might terminate the string literal), so any *special characters* need to be escaped first. In your example you didn't escape ``\``. But of course you can easily parse whatever `JSON.stringify()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes twice (once for javascript, and once for JSON).

```
var text='{"value": "I said, \"hello\""}';
```

should be

```
var text='{"value": "I said, \\"hello\\""}';
```

Comment: No, it should be `var text='{"value": "I said, \\"hello\\""}';`, but yours does work as well because `\"` simply results in `"`. It's not necessary to escape the `"` here though.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for catching that! I've updated my answer.